# How to use a powerhsell serialized object?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have machine that I need to analyze for information.  I use powershell to gather the information into an object and then I write that object out to a file using `Export-Clixml myObject.xml`.

I then try to test import this object using `$placeholder = Import-Clixml myObject.xml` and this works fine as I can see all the methods and access data in the methods.

However, whenever I try to use this object in my program where this type of object is required, I get a `Type Mismatch` error.

Is this not possible with serialized object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the full typename of the objects you deserialized you will see that they begin with "Deserialzed".  For instance if I take a bunch of `System.Diagnostics.Process` objects and export them using Export-Clixml, when I use Import-Clixml to import them, the types are now `Deserialized.System.Diagnostics.Process` objects.  What PowerShell is doing is saving the data out and then giving you access to that again.  You're not getting back live objects. Typically the only method available is `ToString()`.  This is similar to what happens with serialization over remoting.  If you want full fidelity .NET type serialization. I would use one of the .NET serializers such as the BinarySerializer or the XmlSerializer or the newer DataContractSerializer.

Comment: How can I find the binary serializer?

Comment: See the docs on the BinaryFormatter - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.aspx