# How can I make powershell job to return the object type I want?

Tags: powershell, jobs, start-job

I'm trying to use powershell job in order to build a TreeView object and return it, instead, I get PSObject type everytime the job ends.

I've tried returning the TreeView object in many ways, like adding [System.Windows.Forms.TreeView] before the variable name in the return line, or as a part of an array, nothing seems to return the expected result

```bsh
$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock{
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
    $Tree = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TreeView
    Return $Tree
}
Wait-Job $job
$Output = Receive-Job $job
```

```bsh
$Output.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     PSObject                                 System.Object
```

Comment: It seems that you can't get a live object from a job due a to serialization/deserialization.

Comment: montonero, are you sure there is not a single way to achieve that? maybe using different commands?


     iRon, as you can see, I did use Receive-Job in the last line of the code and showed the results in the 2nd code block.

Comment: @montonero is right. Observe the error message from an attempt to cast `$Output` as expected type `[System.Windows.Forms.TreeView]$Output`

Comment: You do get back a TreeView object, but it's wrapped up by PowerShell due to the way you are creating/returning it.  Use `$Output | Get-Member` to see the underlying object (`Deserialized.System.Windows.Forms.TreeView`).  You can access all the expected properties in the usual way: `$Output.Nodes`.  Note, that as already pointed out, this is not a 'live' object as it has been deserialised as part of the job, so will have some limitations (mainly lack of methods).

Comment: @EnTm You could try some advanced serialization classes from .NET like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18747942/how-to-use-a-powerhsell-serialized-object) although I didn't tried it for myself.

Comment: Thank you all guys, I now understand how powershell job works.  
And thanks to your guidance I looked for a different method to achieve my goal and found one that uses another powershell instance to modify my object (my first goal was also to create the object within the job, but I can work with that) 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15382728/passing-native-object-to-background-jobs